# What is the best way to handle prop function arguments in react/typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I have this

```
type Props = {
  onClose: () => void
} 
const MyComponent = ({ onClose }: Props) => {
 // my component
}
```

but then `onClose` could take any function in theory. with maybe an argument.

so I can do: `onClose: (arg) => void` but then what if sometimes this type is `string` and sometimes `number` etc

the only way I can think of is using generics but this gets quite messy I'd have to do something like:

```
type Props<T> = {
  onClose: (arg: T) => void
} 
const MyComponent<T> = ({ onClose }: Props<T>) => {
 // my component
}
```

and what if I have many functions, that would be many generics. is there a nicer/cleaner way to handle this? (I obvs don't want to use `any` either)

Comment: You should use `interface` instead of `type` to handle properties.

Comment: @tinmarfrutos can you explain how that would help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it can be anything, then the type is `any`. Just make the argument optional. Also, use the type definition `FC` instead of setting it on the props. You get type inference for component usage when you do it this way.

```
type Props = {
    onClose: (arg?: any) => void
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ onClose }) => {
    // my component
}
```

Comment: but I don't want any? there are certain types I don't want

Comment: @RedBaron What is your exact use case and how does explicit typing bring value to this use case? I'm trying to figure out how/why it would matte what the real type is if it's a callback that can accept an arbitrary value type

Answer (score 0):

You can replace Props definition by the following.

```js
type ComponentAllowedPropsKind = unknown
type Props<T> = Record<string,ComponentAllowedPropsKind>
const MyComponent<T> = ({ onClose }: Props<T>) => {
    // my component
}
```

You can restrict kinds of props more instead of `unknown`.
You can restrict props name more instead of `string` like.
This code design will force you to handle **type guard** inside your component if you want to use those props.